# How to understand this paragraph?

Tags: grammaire

> Une autre cause accentue le noircissement pour certains cidres: il existe toujours dans le cidre *des* sels de fer qui, comme on le sait, précipitent le tanin en noir; il *en* résulte une coloration beaucoup plus foncée que celle qui serait produite par la simple oxydation du tanin.

I'm a bit lost in

1. It seems "the other cause that brings the ciders darkening" is "the salt of iron"? But how to understand the *des* in "*il existe toujours dans le cidre des sels de fer*" ? This shall mean "*In the cider there always exists the salt of iron*", then the *des* seems messed the structure up .
2. How to understand the *en* in *il en résulte une coloration*?
3. I'm also quite lost in the last clause : ...  *que celle qui serait produite par la simple oxydation du tanin*. What does it mean, and what does *celle* refers to?

Comment: You have three different questions here. Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) "**Des**" is a plural so it's "In the cider there is always **iron salts**"

2/3) "**en**" is short for "il existe toujours dan le cidre des sels de fer qui, comme on le sait, précipitent le tanin en noir" while "**celle**" refer to "coloration" : "***this*** leads to a darker coloration than **the one** that would be produced by the tannins's oxydation alone"

Comment: Thank you, now I guess I got it : 1. *des* means "the", not "of the" ( de les). 2/3: *en* seems help the *il* to refer to the clause in front.

Comment: Well "des" is the plural form of "a/un", while "les" is the plural form of "the/le" but "des" have no translation in english. Un chat : a cat, le chat  : the cat, les/des chats : cats. More details : http://www.languageguide.org/french/grammar/articles/

Comment: thanks! There's no 1-1 mapping, got it.